# POST request - Not working with Node and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I just started learning Node and Express for a simple project but for some reason I cannot get POST to work. My browser gives me an error: Cannot POST /

Any assistance with this issue is appreciated. Thank you.

My code is below:

```
let express = require("express")
let ourApp = express()

ourApp.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

ourApp.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send(`
    <form action='/' method='POST'>
      <h2>What color is the sky on a clear and sunny day?</h2>
      <input name="skyColor" autocomplete="off">
      <button>Submit Answer</button>
    </form>
  `)
})

ourApp.post("/answer", function(req, res) {
  if (req.body.skyColor.toUpperCase() == "BLUE") {
    res.send(`
      <p>Congrats, that is the correct answer.</p>
      <a href="/">Back to homepage</a>
    `)
  } else {
    res.send(`
    <p>Sorry, that is incorrect.</p>
    <a href="/">Back to homepage</a>
    `)
  }
})

ourApp.get("/answer", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Are you lost there is nothing to see here.")
})

ourApp.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Your form `action` should be `/answer`, not `/`

Comment: Oh, geez. I feel like a total noob and should have tried '/answer' before I posted. Sorry about that. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

For the `"/"` route, the `form` you return should have `action="/answer"`, not `action="/"`

Your other routes should stay the same, and pretty sure that should work.

```
ourApp.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send(`
    <form action='/answer' method='POST'>
      <h2>What color is the sky on a clear and sunny day?</h2>
      <input name="skyColor" autocomplete="off">
      <button>Submit Answer</button>
    </form>
  `)
})
```

Comment: `express.json()` is not appropriate for this sort of POST request. OP would need `express.urlencoded()` which is what they already have

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting wrong endpoint.
You should post to for example http://localhost:3000/answer.

And one more thing if you want to pass JSON data in body you need to use body-parser middleware.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: What makes you think OP wants to parse JSON? They already have an appropriate body parser with `ourApp.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`

Comment: @phil yes I saw that I am saying just in case you want to use it you can use that.

Comment: Express comes with its own JSON body parser now, there's no need to include `body-parser`

Comment: Is it, thanks I was not aware that it comes with own body-parser.